# Order function in R cannot be reversed with - or rev() when column has alpha and numeric characters

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

First time I ever cared to sort because I need to report this in a specific way. Typically, smallest to largest sort in excel on column quarter returns YTD, 3,2,1. etc. However, I cannot sort using Order(-begin$Quarter) or rev(begin$Quarter). Other solutions with mix sort prevent me from then also sorting other columns, like here I want to sort by quarter then segment. I have dput examples.

Thanks,

```
begin<- structure(list(Quarter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "YTD"), class = "factor"), 
    Segment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Beverages", "Food"), class = "factor"), Person = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Chris", "Jackie", 
    "Josh"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 7, 
    7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))


end<- structure(list(Quarter = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "YTD"), class = "factor"), 
    Segment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Beverages", "Food"), class = "factor"), Person = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Chris", "Jackie", 
    "Josh"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 7, 1, 
    6, 7, 6, 7, 9, 3, 8, 3, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8, 4, 7, 4, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: You need to convert the Quarter and Segment columns from factor to character (or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when importing the data). Once you've done this it will sort correctly.

Comment: I had it as character to begin with. It does work with factors:  Warning message:
In Ops.factor(e$Quarter) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors or with Character: Error in -e$Quarter : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: If `x` is a factor, `sort(x)` and `order(x)` will not (necessarily) sort/order `x` alphabetically, it will sort/order by factor level.

Comment: Once you've converted to character, you can sort by `Quarter` and `Segment`, in decreasing and increasing alphabetical order respectively, with `begin[with(begin, order(Quarter, Segment, method = 'radix', decreasing = c(T, F))),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

begin %>%
  arrange(desc(Quarter), Person, Segment)
```